# Cells apears blank but cannot be replaced

Tags: microsoft-excel

I try to replace blank cells by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> function, however, there is one cell that cannot be replaced, although it appears empty. But when I use data filter, it is shown as "blanks".

Could anyone suggest a solution to this "blank but not blank" cells issue.

A copy of my sample file can be found [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?8x8f8621x51x1en)

Answer (score 1):

These are space characters. Just find 'space' and replace by nothing.

The cell by definition is not 'blank' but contains characters that are not visible in normal conditions. Filtering however will show them as being blank.

Answer (score 0):

Some special characters are rendered as space. Replacing with space will not do you any good. Try replacing with Ctrl+H with the character you copy from that "empty" space.